# Fastest way to load text files into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have about 1000 g-zipped files, where each file contain a text file with approximately 5 million rows and 7 to 10 columns. Opening the g-zipped file only takes 0.1s or so using the `gzip.open()` command. However, I need to find specific rows in each file, which I can easily do when the text is in data frame format. My problem is that by using Pandas `read_csv()` function, it takes about 25-30s for each file. Multiply that by 1000, and this will take forever.

So my question is therefore: Are there any ways to optimize this loading ? I know I could use multiprocessing to do more at a time, but it's the initial load into a data frame that seems to be my bottleneck.

Comment: It doesn't take `0.1s or so` to open your file. It is just the declaration of the file that is instant. looping over your file will take as much time as pandas, even more. Pandas needs to read your file to put it in memory, that is why it is taking a long time.

Comment: If you want to load these files faster better not to save them as a text file. You can use feather/parquet format to read/write dataframes faster. Then you can use read_feather/read_parquet to read df faster. I guess feather is the fastest available opt.

Comment: I am not creating these files. And they are actually not even text files, they have no extension. But they can be opened like a text file. So that particular thing I can't do much about, unfortunately.

Comment: @Steven So you are basically saying, that there isn't much to do to optimize the load speed ?

Comment: @DenverDang Almost. Pandas is not responsible for the delay, the size of the files is. But you asked the right thing : how to perform multitask. That's the only way you can reduce your process time properly. The rest depends on your CPU and RAM.